# Swift instance members & functions calls, could someone please clarify?

Tags: ios, swift, function

I'm practicing functions in an Xcode project (not playground, if that matters) and when I set the constant's function name to the above function's name, Xcode won't let me call it.

In other functions I've done the same thing I haven't had this error, I don't know why it's being triggered. I've tried putting the "let fun" constant into it's own struct but that just throws up a different error.

[image]

Comment: Do not show pictures of code, please.

Answer (score 3):

Your `let fun = playstation(...` is code. It is an executable command. Code consisting of an executable command cannot just live anywhere. It cannot exist just free-floating the way you have it. It must live in a method. For example you could put it inside your `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Does it have to be in a separate method than the one I'm linking it to? I put it in the func playstation baskets and Xcode says "Code after 'return' will never be executed".

Comment: Every function is just a set of instructions. It does not run unless someone tells it to. Clearly you have a desire to tell `playstation` to run, but I have no idea _why_ you want it to run or _when_. That is what you must decide. When you do then you can determine where you want to put your call so that it will happen at the right moment.

Answer (score 3):

I am sure you know this, but I would like to say that learning the basics/fundamentals of the Swift language is really good if you use playgrounds for that or any other online IDEs which support Swift language.

Swift Playgrounds Experience is very, very different than what an iOS dev has to do later, i.e. when it actually comes to building an app.
Of course in app making, the Swift language is used, and one uses the knowledge he practiced using playgrounds. BUT!

When it comes to storyboards, ViewControllers, etc., one has to understand that this time, it is all about OOP (classes and structs).

It is about managing views, loading them, displaying UIView objects, implementing logic, saving/loading data...

So as people mentioned above, here you are creating an **instance** **method** and trying to use it as a **regular** function inside that `Class`.
To be able to use this function **as you expect**, you have to create an object/instance of this class, then you can call this function.

[image: In this picture, you may see that using a static keyword also might be a solution. static func(){} means that this function belongs to the class itself. You access that func by using the full name of the type/class.]

In this picture, you may see that using a `static` keyword also might be a solution. `static func(){}` means that this function belongs to the class itself. You access that func by using the full name of the type/class.

Comment: Thanks, I'm starting to see the differences between playground and a real project.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call an instance method to initialize this same exact instance property, so you will need to convert to a lazy var like so:

```swift
lazy var fun = playStation(game: "Monsters")
```

This way, the `playStation(game: "Monsters")` call will be triggered lazily, in the exact moment when the `fun` property will be called for the first time. This can be very useful, especially when performing more intensive tasks. The quirk with using `lazy` keyword is that it can only be used with `var`, which means the property can be mutated or set again - we lose immutability of `let` constants.

But maybe you do not want to store the `fun` value as an instance property and only want to get it once? You could then move it into the `viewDidLoad` implementation, so the `fun` is no longer an instance property but a local one, available only within the `viewDidLoad` method scope.

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let fun = playStation(game: "Monsters")
    // do what you want with the `fun` value.

    // maybe set it as text to some label?
    myLabel.text = fun
}
```

You can read more about Lazy Initialization in [this blogpost](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-lazy-property-initialization/), also make sure to read the [official documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html).

Comment: Never heard of a lazy var, I'll check it out thanks.